# Accessing exported variables in a shell function

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there a way to make use of exported variables in `shell` function without the need for sub-make?

Take the following example.

```
FOO := BAR

.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES:

.PHONY: buzz
buzz:
    $(info buzz)
    $(error finish)

.PHONY: fizz
fizz: $(if $(shell echo $$FOO),buzz,)
    $(info fizz)
    $(MAKE) fizz
```

If I run the `fizz` target like so I get the following output.

```bash
$ make fizz
fizz
make fizz
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jshbrntt/test'
buzz
Makefile:8: *** finish.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jshbrntt/test'
make: *** [Makefile:13: fizz] Error 2
```

As you can see only the second run of `make fizz` had the `shell` function expanded and cause the `buzz` target to also run.

Comment: Why are you using `$(shell)` in a recipe instead of executing the wanted shell command directly there?

Comment: Because I'm calling a program (not `echo`) that reads variables from the environment, I'll update my test example to try and make this clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make use of exported variables in `shell` function without the need for sub-make?

**No.**

Remember always that GNU `make` functions such as `$(shell)` are evaluated while the makefile is being parsed, not when `make` runs recipes (refer to [section 3.7 of the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html#Reading-Makefiles)), regardless of where in the makefile the `$(shell)` invocation appears.  `make` determines which variables are exported based on its own environment and the combination of *all* rules and `export` / `unexport` directives in the makefile, potentially including rules and / or directives generated via `$(shell)` and other functions.  In this way it ensures that it is consistent about the environment used to execute recipes.

Although it is conceivable that `make` would expose expose intermediate forms of its export list to the `$(shell)` function (and its documentation doesn't clearly specify whether it does so), as a practical matter it would be surprising for it to do so, and your experiment shows that it does not do.  And although the manual does not explicitly speak directly to the question, it should be noted that its documentation of `export`, *etc*. is in [a section entitled *Communicating Variables to a Sub-`make`*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html#index-compatibility-in-exporting).

Personally, I recommend avoiding `$(shell)` (and `$(wildcard)`) altogether.  If you do use `$(shell)` then I recommend reserving such use to outside recipes.  Inside recipes, use shell code directly.  This is clearer, certainly in terms of makefile semantics (what is evaluated when), but often in terms of the actual code, too.  For your particular example, that might look like so:

```
FOO := BAR
.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES:
.PHONY: fizz
fizz:
    @echo fizz
    @if test -n "$$FOO"; then echo FOO found; else echo FOO missing; make fizz; fi
```

Comment: The use of `printenv` was a substitute for another command I'm using that depends on an exported environment variable, so I ended up having to use sub-make.

Comment: @jshbrntt, I'm glad you got it working.  I observe, however, that the alternative presented in the example in this answer is also a command that depends on an exported environment variable.  Use a sub-`make` if that works and seems logical to you, but I don't see any reason why that would be necessary.

Comment: I've updated my example again to demonstrate why I was using the `$(shell ...)` function I essentially want a conditional dependency, dependant on the output of a shell command which depends on an environment variable set by the `Makefile`.

Comment: May I ask for your caveat about `$(wildcard)`?

Comment: @Vroomfondel, my view is that the makefile should be the complete and authoritative source on how to perform the build.  That is not achieved when `$(wildcard)` is used in any meaningful way, because that incorporates the current contents of the filesystem as part of the build instructions.  And this has practical effects.  For example, you cannot put a source file in the project source directory without it being included in the build, and on the flip side, if a source file is accidentally removed then it's a lot harder to troubleshoot the resulting breakage.

Comment: Isn't this also the case with pattern rules?

Comment: No, @Vroomfondel, it is not.  At least, not to the same extent.  A pattern rule (or a suffix rule) comes into play only if it matches a target that needs to be built.  If the choice of targets that need to be built is driven explicitly by the makefile (*i.e.* without using `$(wildcard)` or `$(shell)`) then the situation is, generally speaking, controlled to my satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

In all current versions of GNU make, exported variables are not sent to the `shell` function.  There are some very nasty recursive behaviors that can happen (what if you write `export BAR = $(shell echo $$FOO)` ???)

In the next release of GNU make, make variables *will* be exported to the `shell` function.

However, there's never any good reason to use `shell` in a recipe.  The recipe *is* running in a shell, so you can just write the commands that you want directly.  So if your example is accurate in that you want to use this facility in a recipe, just take out the `shell` invocation:

```
.PHONY: fizz
fizz:
        @echo fizz
        @test -n $$FOO && echo FOO found || echo FOO missing
```